# okhttp interceptor chain created multiple times during process interceptor

Tags: okhttp

I'm learning the source code of okhttp3, i have a little confuse that why okhttp create multiple chains (RealInterceptorChain) in each interceptor. Looks like only need one chain to manage the interceptor list.

Answer (score 0):

Each chain instance behaves differently when `proceed()` is called. For example, the 3rd chain is the only one that calls the 4th chain.